# Month,date help for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Here's the question I need help with:

In name sequence, list mortal ID, first and last name and birth date for anyone whose plan expires after 1999.  Display the date with this format: Jan. 22, 2001

I've got all the code I nned except for one part, see below:

```
SQL> SELECT MORTAL.MORTAL_ID,
  2  TO_CHAR(DOB,'MONTH DD YYYY ') AS DATE_OF_BIRTH,
  3  FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME AS EXPIRES_AFTER_1999
  4  FROM MORTAL
  5  JOIN INSURED ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = INSURED.MORTAL_ID
  6  JOIN POLICY ON INSURED.POLICY_ID=POLICY.POLICY_ID
  7  WHERE TO_CHAR(POLICY.EXPIRE_DATE, 'YYYY') <= 1999
  8  ORDER BY LAST_NAME;

 MORTAL_ID DATE_OF_BIRTH        EXPIRES_AFTER_1999
---------- -------------------- -------------------------
       106 FEBRUARY  22 1995    Charles JOHNSON
       105 JANUARY   31 1972    Tamara Johnson
       107 JUNE      22 1972    Randy Johnson
       120 MAY       20 1980    BEVERLY Schwitzer-Pless
       119 MAY       12 1962    Danielle Schwitzer-Pless
       111 JUNE      30 1953    Kimberly VAUBEL
       110 MARCH     02 1947    John Vaubel
```

I need the date to be in this format:
Jan. 22, 2001

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format you need:

```
select to_char( sysdate, 'MON. dd, YYYY' ) from dual
```

see it here at fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20997

And if you want the month in camelCase e.g. `Jan.` just change the format a bit like this:

```
select to_char( sysdate, 'Mon. dd, YYYY' ) from dual
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20998

The Oracle Docs for all date formats: [DateTime Format Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair out, bookmarked the SQL fiddle site.